# Remove cclayer once all actions finished on its children

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have a CCLayer which has multiple children (Sprites, CCMenuItemImages ets). And these children are having their children (mostly CCLabel*** or CCMenuItemImages). So I want to fade out the all the grand-children and children of the layer and then once all are faded I want to remove the CCLayer.

I am able to apply fade action to the hierarchy. But if I do [CCLayer removeFromParentWithCleanup:YES], then it removes immediately while still some children are running with fade action.

So my question is how can i remove the parent layer once all the gran-children and children are faded (opacity = 0).

Edit: Here is a code snippet

```
for(CCNode *node in itemLayer.children)
{
    for(CCSprite *sprite in parentLayer.children)
    {
        for(id item in sprite.children)
            [item runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:2.5f opacity:0]];
        [sprite runAction:[CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:2.5f opacity:0]];
    }
}
```

itemLayer is the Parent CCLayer which has a CCNode *node. node is having children and each children have their children. So I want to remove the node and its parent itemLayer once all the actions completes on children and gran-children. How to do this?

Comment: I am using COCOS2d 2.1 for IOS

Comment: When fading the layer, use a sequence : fade, callBlockN , where in the call block you will have the [self removeFromParentWithCleanup:YES]; . Self IS the layer.

Comment: I have edited my question with code snippet. Could you please help in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your top level container a CCNodeRGBA and set in the init :

```
self.cascadeColorEnabled=YES;
self.cascadeOpacityEnabled=YES;
self.opacity=255;
```

When you run a CCFadeAction on that, the node will do all the forklifting of cascading down to children and grand-children. At the end of the fade action,

```
id fade = [CCFadeTo actionWithDuration:2.5 opacity:0];
id done = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
    [self removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
    // plus whatever else you see fit
}];
id seq  = [CCSequence actions:fade, done, nil];
[self runAction:seq];
```

ob cit : from memory, not compiled nor tested, YMMV

Comment: The propagation happens all during the update cycle, before the draw call from the root node. Whether you compute top-leaf to lowest-leaf or the reverse, you would not be able to see the difference.

Comment: Accidentally deleted the earlier comment. However I tried your way as in answer. But the opacity is not propagating to the grand children of the CCLayerColor (self). What i am doing wrong?

Comment: interesting : CCLayerColor descends from CCNode (not CCNodeRGBA) ... duh. I avoided this by encapsulating all into a top level CCNodeRGBA object (as self), and having my own version of CCLayerColor.

Comment: Thank you. Still you gave me the starting point in the answer. I will take it further.